# How to get module image name from an arbitrary address in Windows kernel space?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, portable-executable

I'm trying to see how I can get a loaded module image name from an arbitrary address from the kernel code.

In user mode I would do this:

```
void* pAddr;
VOID* pBase;
WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH] = {0};

//Get address of some function in some module (just to test it)
pAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "GetCurrentProcess");

//Get module base address
RtlPcToFileHeader(pAddr, &pBase);

//Get module image file name
GetModuleFileNameEx(GetCurrentProcess(), (HMODULE)pBase, buff, SIZEOF(buff));
```

Is there a way to do the same in kernel mode if I have `pAddr` that can point to some address in kernel or user space?

---

EDIT: While waiting for the answer I came up with my own code (using undocumented way of traversing PEB):

```
#ifdef CALLING_FROM_KERNEL_MODE
//Kernel mode
TEB* pTEB = (TEB*)PsGetCurrentThreadTeb();

#else
//User mode

#if defined(_M_X64)
//64-bit
TEB* pTEB = reinterpret_cast<TEB*>(__readgsqword(reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&static_cast<NT_TIB*>(nullptr)->Self)));
#else
//32-bit
TEB* pTEB = reinterpret_cast<TEB*>(__readfsdword(reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&static_cast<NT_TIB*>(nullptr)->Self)));
#endif

#endif

PEB* p_PEB = pTEB->ProcessEnvironmentBlock;
PEB_LDR_DATA* pPLD = p_PEB->Ldr;

const WCHAR* pModName = NULL;

LIST_ENTRY* pLE = &pPLD->InMemoryOrderModuleList;
LIST_ENTRY* pLE_Head = pLE;
while(pLE_Head != pLE->Flink)
{
    PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLDTE = CONTAINING_RECORD(pLE, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);

    size_t szcbSizeOfImg = (size_t)pLDTE->Reserved3[1];
    if((size_t)pAddr - (size_t)pLDTE->DllBase < szcbSizeOfImg)
    {
        pModName = pLDTE->FullDllName.Buffer;

        break;
    }

    pLE = pLE->Flink;
}
```

The problem is that although it works from a user-mode, from a kernel mode `PsGetCurrentThreadTeb()` seems to return `NULL`. Does this mean kernel threads do not have a `TEB`?

Comment: `ZwQuerySystemInformation` or `Nt*` (depend from previous mode) with SystemModuleInformation and iterate via `RTL_PROCESS_MODULES`

Comment: on what thread you call this ? kernel mode threads have no TEB. it 0. so i assume you call it in context of kernel mode thread

Comment: @RbMm yeah kernel mode. So how about PEB? And also side question. If there's no TEB why is there `nt!PsGetCurrentThreadTeb` function?

Comment: because `PsGetCurrentThreadTeb` return value of TEB for the current thread. what here unclear ? *So how about PEB?* - how about - for what process ?

Comment: and look like you not understand. i mean in context of what thread you call. not from kernel or user mode. exist only kernel mode threads. exist user mode threads.

Comment: @RbMm: I don't know the context. I'm using it from a callback function.

Comment: more exactly say [*system thread*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-pscreatesystemthread) - you call from *system thread*

Comment: so what want if don't know the context ? what you try do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by creating list of all loaded modules via `ZwQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemModuleInformation`

```
void fgt(PVOID *Callers, ULONG Count)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x10000;
    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES prpm = (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, cb))
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, prpm, cb, &cb)))
            {
                do 
                {
                    PVOID Caller = *Callers++;

                    if (ULONG NumberOfModules = prpm->NumberOfModules)
                    {
                        PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION Modules = prpm->Modules;

                        do 
                        {
                            if ((SIZE_T)Caller - (SIZE_T)Modules->ImageBase < Modules->ImageSize)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("%p> %s\n", Caller, Modules->FullPathName);
                                break;
                            }
                        } while (Modules++, --NumberOfModules);
                    }

                } while (--Count);
            }
            ExFreePool(prpm);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very clever way to do memory allocation in a loop, by the way. Your method works great for retrieving all loaded drivers. I was also thinking to do the same for user-mode addresses (for a code from a kernel mode.) While waiting I was working on my own method. I posted it in my question above. Do you know why am I getting a NULL teb there?

Comment: Btw, [here's definitions](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40696-list-loaded-drivers-with-ntquerysysteminformation/) of undocumented structs in the code above.